# Problems getting the value from two dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie in html/javascript languages.

I'm trying to get value from both combined `dropdowns` and show it. My problem is that I'am doing something wrong and I can't understand what.

Note: As a plus, I want to add more `dropdowns`.

Follows the html:

```
    <form>
    <select name="courselevel" id="courselevel" style="width:120px">
        <option>Courses level</option>
        <option value="1">level 5</option>
        <option value="2">level 4</option>
        <option value="3">level 3</option>
        <option value="4">level 2</option>
        <option value="5">level 1</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
   <select name="tolevel" id="tolevel" style="width:120px">
        <option>To level</option>
        <option value="1">level 4</option>
        <option value="2">level 3</option>
        <option value="3">level 2</option>
        <option value="4">level 1</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input name="button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="return validate()" />   
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
<div id="total"></div>
</form>
```

Follows my `js`:

```
var courselevel = document.getElementById('courselevel'),
    tolevel = document.getElementById('tolevel');

    window.onload = function(){
courselevel = document.getElementById('courselevel'),
tolevel = document.getElementById('tolevel');

courselevel.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    switch (level.selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            var courselevelList1   = ["Select level"];
            var courselevellist2    = ["Select level2"];
            fillList(courselevel, courselevelList1);
            fillList(tolevel, courselevelList2);
            break;

        case 1:

            var courselevelList   = ["Select level", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"];
            var courselevelList2    = ["Select level2", "4", "3", "2", "1" ];
            fillList(level, courselevelList1);
            fillList(tolevel, courselevelList2);
            break;

    }
});

};




function fillList(el, items) {
     el.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = items[i];
        option.text = items[i];
        el.add(option);
    }
}


window.validate = function() {
    var courselevelvalue = parseFloat(courselevel.options[courselevel.selectedIndex].value),
        tolevelvalue = parseInt(tolevel.options[tolevel.selectedIndex].value),
        totaltolevelvalue = courselevelvalue + tolevelvalue;

    total.innerHTML = totaltolevelvalue;    
    return totaltolevelvalue;
```

Comment: If your are not using jQuery in your code please remove its tag

Comment: done, thanks for notice

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a clear question but in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzvjd87u/) that I made with your code you can see that the problem is that `total` is not defined

you have this:

```
total.innerHTML = totaltolevelvalue;
```

but there is no declaration for `total`

perhaps you have not included your code in its entirety

Comment: alright so i added <div id="total"></div> and it seems to work. thanks for your insight!

Comment: @Adasr - glad to have helped. please mark as answer and vote up.